# The meaning of Down by

Tags: prepositions

If I say "down by 40" pounds does it mean I lost 40 pounds or that all what is left is 40 pounds

Comment: by is what you lost

Comment: "down to 40 pounds" is what is left.

Answer (score 1):

The word (preposition) *by*, used after *up* or *down* and followed by a number or measure, indicates the amount something has risen or fallen.  So if your weight goes down by forty pounds, and your previous weight was 154 pounds, your new weight is 154-40 = 114 pounds.

But I expect you mean pounds (money)!  So if you start out with £154.00 in your bank account and that sum goes down by £40, you are left with £154-£40 = £114.